# Sistema de deleção do usuário por parte do próprio usuário

Tags: php, mysql

Há algum tempo venho tentando desenvolver um sistema de deleção de conta por parte do usuário, tipo o que presenciamos no facebook e twitter onde nas configurações do usuário, o mesmo pode optar pode deletar sua conta. Porém minhas tentavas foram frustadas.

Então resolvi vir aqui, como sempre. Algum tutorial passo a passo?

[image]

Este é o código php que tentei (fecharcontar.php):

```html
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if ($usuario) {
 if (isset($_POST['sim'])) {
  header("location: /configuracoes");
 }
  if (isset($_POST['nao'])) {
  $fecharconta = mysql_query("UPDATE usuario SET `fechada`='$fechada' WHERE id='$id'");
  echo "Sua conta foi fechada";
  session_destroy();
 }
}
else {
 die("Você não está logado!");
}
```

e este é o HTML:

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="conteudo-fundo">
   <form action="fecharconta.php" method="POST">
    Você tem certeza de que pretende fechar sua conta?<br>
    <input type="submit" name="no" value="Não, me leve de volta">
    <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Sim, eu tenho certeza">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

E destacado em vermelho é a coluna que criei no banco de dados para verificar se o usuário está ativo eu inativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Por fim, depois de tanto tentar e com dicas da comunidade, consegui resolver o problema.**

**Consegui resolver o problema, vou disponibilizar aqui o código que utilizei e as etapas.**

Este é o código html que tem um action apontando para **desativar-conta.php**

```html
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="conteudo-fundo">
   <form action="view/desativar-conta.php" method="POST">
    Você tem certeza de que pretende fechar sua conta?<br>
    <input type="submit" name="no" value="Não, me leve de volta">
    <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Sim, eu tenho certeza">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Este é o código do arquivo **desativar-conta.php**

```html
<?php


include_once("../php/dados.php");

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

 $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='$login_cookie'");
 $dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
session_start();
if ($id) {
 if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
  header("location: /configuracoes");
 }
 if (isset($_POST['yes'])) {
  $desativar = mysql_query ("UPDATE usuario SET desativada='yes' WHERE id='$id'");
  echo "Sua conta foi desativada!";
  session_destroy();
 }
}
else{
 die(header("location: ./../"));
}
?>
```

Quando o Usuário clicar no input com valor: "Sim, eu tenho certeza", automaticamente mudará o valor da coluna **desativada** no banco de dados.

Adicionei ainda ao código php de login o seguinte: **desativada = 'no'**, o que só permite que o usuário faça o Login quando a coluna **desativada** estiver **'no'**.

O código dentro desse **login.php**, dentro da variável que seleciona os dados do banco de dados ficou o seguinte:

**SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha' AND desativada='no'**

E na foto abaixo, destacado em laranja está a coluna **desativada**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o que tentou amigo para que possamos ajudar, basicamente é só ao clicar no botão executar um DELETE no banco de dados apagando o usuário. Ou um UPDATE mudando uma coluna binaria no registro do usuário mostrando se ele está ou não ativo

Comment: Me parece que a verificação do php está invertida...Você verifica se existe uma variável do tipo POST['sim'] que não faz o delete... Será isso mesmo?

Comment: fiz a alteração corrigindo **POST['sim']** para **POST['no']** e **POST['nao']** para **POST['yes']**. Porém o código **body** do **html** não aparece quando insiro o **fecharconta.php** no mesmo arquivo **html**, o que é estranho, não estou entendendo porque está a sumir.

Comment: É melhor deixar o código em outro arquivo, porque senão o código é executado assim que carrega o formulário e pode acontecer isso de não aparecer.